# Fail the entire run at VS unit test even if conitinue after failure is checked

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a c# unit testing code at VS in which I like to fail the entire run if a specific [TestMethod] is failed, even though I have checked the "continue in case of a failure".

--adding more detail--

```
[TestMethod] \\should fail the entire run
public void ImportentTest(){}

[TestMethod] \\ should continue to the next testmethode if fail
public void LessImportentTest(){}
```

Comment: It is better if you can add your code into the question

Comment: Why do you want to stop the whole test?

Comment: Have you tired using the run all tests in test explorer?

Comment: yes, it does manage to run all tests but the issue is that i want some test the fail the entire run nevertheless because failing at them will fail all the next tests also

Comment: Why not just run that test first then run other ones separately afterwards if ok?